# Pass a value from a function to another function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have a piece of code, **disclaimer: I have not written a lot this code, others have helped.** and i want to pass a parameter within it.

This is supposed to turn a binary number into a decimal, further converting the decimal to a binary.

If you look near the bottom, there's an input, taking 1111 as an example binary number, it turns into 15 as a decimal, which i want 15 to turn into a hexadecimal, **not 1111**.

How do i make it so that the second function, `two()` uses 15? I have a class and a constructor, i want to know how i can pass the end result of the function `one()` to the function `two()`.

```
import os,time

class Helper:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def one(self):
        b1 = self.num
        b2 = 0
        d1 = 0
        p = 0
        while(b1 != 0): 
            b2 = b1 % 10
            d1 = d1 + b2 * pow(2, p)
            b1 = b1//10
            p = p + 1
        print (d1)


    def two(self):
        n = self.num
        hex_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
        reversed_number = ""
        while n > 0:
            remainder = n % 16
            n -= remainder
            n //= 16
            reversed_number += str(hex_values[remainder])

        print(reversed_number[::-1])


os.system('clear')
print
print ("Input any number.")
n = Helper(int(input(">> ")))

time.sleep(1)
n.one()

time.sleep(1)
print
n.two()
print
time.sleep(1)
```

If you look at the function `one()` there is a print, i want to pass that value, not the variable `b1` or the value of the input the user gave.

Comment: I know this might seem like a repeat, there is a similar question to this, however it is in completely different context, and i'm not able to understand that very well ;)

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that your code simply prints stuff to the screen, and then basically forgets it. The function should `return` the value rather than just print it (and actually it would probably be a better design to *only* `return` and have the caller `print` or do whatever it wants with the returned value).

Comment: A number has one value, regardless of the base it's represented in. If you want different representation of the same number try: `print("{0:d} {1:X} {2:b}".format(15, 15, 15))`. Conversely, check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int. So, the whole (end goal of the) exercise looks a bit like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: so i should do ```return d1```?

Comment: Yeah, do that and take it from there. The rest of the code needs to be adapted correspondingly of course.

Comment: CristiFati, is this related to passing the value of an integer to another function?

Comment: @tripleee thank you for your answer, however as i'm a bit fresh to python, would you mind briefing for what should i do further?
So i return the value d1, ```return d1``` then i attempt to take the value in the second function?

Comment: The answer from olisch shows exactly how to do this.

Comment: Tangentially, probably remove the `sleep`s, they only seem to slow down things which don't need to be slowed down at all.

Comment: just for dramatic effect :p

Comment: Here is a refactoring: https://ideone.com/3xVjJY ... there appears to be a bug in the conversion to binary but I didn't try to address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is s way to solve it

```
import os,time

class Helper:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def one(self):
        b1 = self.num
        b2 = 0
        d1 = 0
        p = 0
        while(b1 != 0):
            b2 = b1 % 10
            d1 = d1 + b2 * pow(2, p)
            b1 = b1//10
            p = p + 1
        print (d1)
        return d1 # set the output of the function


    def two(self, n):
        hex_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
        reversed_number = ""
        while n > 0:
            remainder = n % 16
            n -= remainder
            n //= 16
            reversed_number += str(hex_values[remainder])

        print(reversed_number[::-1])


os.system('clear')
print
print ("Input any number.")
n = Helper(int(input(">> ")))

time.sleep(1)
decimal = n.one() # you define a variable as the output of n.one()

time.sleep(1)
print
n.two(decimal) # you pass the output of n.one() to n.two()
print
time.sleep(1)
```

You can set an output for your function n.one() using the *return* keyword
the syntax is: *return {value}*, so if the value you want to return is *d1* simply type

```
return d1
```

Use a variable to capture the output of n.one

```
decimal = n.one()
```

at this point to display the output of *n.one()* you could type

```
print(decimal)
```

instead of printing it in the function *n.one()*
now make the function *n.who()* take the argument you passed

```
def two(self, n):
```

and delete `n = self.num`

finally you pass the output of *n.one()* to *n.two()*

```
n.two(decimal)
```

Hope this solved your issue

Comment: Uh, it still used the input as the num for the function ```two()```

Comment: It works for me. Try to copy and paste to be sure you didn't miss anything

Comment: IT WORKED :D Thanks~! i realised i had an error in my code that's why it didnt work before!

Answer (score 1):

your `one` method needs to return a value instead of printing it, so that you can save the value to a variable. Your `two` method then needs a parameter in order to pass the previous value.

```
def one(self):
    ...
    return d1

def two(self, value):
    ...

v = n.one()
n.two(v)
```

As an altenative, you can save the result of `one` method to an additional instance variable.

Comment: It's not clear how this "doesn't appear to work"; probably you did something else or didn't understand exactly how to refactor your code to use this.'

Comment: did i mention i'm pretty new to python, it is most likely the latter

Comment: i can't exactly mark this correct as it hasn't worked for me, i'm gonna do more testing on this, wait please.

Comment: I GIVE UP IM USING ```GLOBAL``` NOW

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value instead of printing it.

```
def one( self ):
    [...]
    return d1
```

If you only need the output of one() as input to two() you can also skip the assignment to a variable. one() evaluates to a numeric value and you can directly pass it.

```
h = Helper( int(input( ">> " )) );
h.two( h.one() );
```

Or you make it part of the object, then you can just use it.

```
def one(self):
    [...]
    self.d1 = d1;

def two(self):
    value = self.d1;
    [...]
```

Comment: Actually the object already has the number as the member `self.num`

Comment: yeah that is what i was confused about, i have ```n = self.num``` already tho?

Comment: You have the binary input as number in your object, but not the decimal version, since you only print that. Your method two() works with the decimal input, not the binary.

Comment: Oh and of course you have to keep two() from using the binary input by default. Or do something like 'n = self.one( self.num )' in two().